# Negative top margin in Firefox moves elements to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

When I apply a negative margin-top of -3px in a parent element, all the childs move to the right (in Firefox and IE8) but in Chrome looks perfectly fine (elements are centered).

What can be causing this?

```
<div class="menu-tab">
      <div class="folder-tab">
        <span class="normal-small-text">Ingresar<i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

The margin-top is applied in the class `.menu-tab`

This is in Chrome

[image]

And Firefox

[image]

Comment: We probably need more code / a working example of the problem to be able to help you.

Comment: Check this out http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: You gotta post your "menu-tab" , "folder-tab" and other css classes mentioned in the html code

Comment: @Jeroen
I am gonna open my localhost for a few minutes, here's the example
http://187.156.84.30/

Comment: @dotNetSoldier Check the example here please http://187.156.84.30/

Comment: Not sure what's causing the issue but you might have more luck with "position:relative; top:-3px;"

Comment: @3rror404 That did the trick :D, maybe you want to answer to get the points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this seems to have fixed the issue for you, I'll write it as an answer.

Replace:

```
margin-top: -3px;
```

with:

```
position: relative;
top: -3px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try to define margin in the parent element as `0` `.menu-tab {margin:0;}` then define margin for the child element depending from your needs.

Comment: The problem happened even if the child had the margin negative, but I fixed it with the parent having position relative and top -3px.

Answer (score 0):

Mm, i don't see any reason why to use `margin-top` on that element, you can easily just give it the height of your container as a  `line-height` and it should center automatically, along with `text-align:center` to center the text inside of the container, that should automatically center the text both vertically and horizontally inside its container.